# Set fixed height for bottom sheet dialog fragment in android

Tags: java, android, fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    style="@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.bottomsheet.FilterBottomSheetFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingHorizontal="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="Payment method"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcPaymentMethod"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <View
                style="@style/Divider.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="Bed Size"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcBedSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <View
                style="@style/Divider.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="View"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <View
                style="@style/Divider.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:text="Facilities"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rcFacilities"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="13dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtClearAll"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="Clear All"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnApply"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button"
                android:text="Apply"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/primary" />
        </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is file xml of bottom sheet dialog fragment. I want to set fixed height for fragment when it showed in other fragment. Because in bottom sheet I have recycler view so when I scroll bottom sheet expanded to full screen. I don't want that. I want to set fixed height for it. And I want to button Apply always display at the bottom when I scrool.

[image: Discription]

Answer (score 1):

To full height:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = context?.let { BottomSheetDialog(it, theme) }
    dialog?.setOnShowListener {
        val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val parentLayout =
            bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        parentLayout?.let { bottomSheet ->
            val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
            setupFullHeight(bottomSheet)
            behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
    return dialog ?: super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
}

private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

- button Apply, You can set top of view, or stick to bottom use RelativeLayout

Comment: I have created relative layout contains button Apply in file design bottom sheet. But it don't work

Comment: Can you write code by java. Because I am beginner android java

Answer (score 0):

Add Layout custom fix height

android:layout_height="500dp"

Add Layout peek height

app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"